# Remove comments and add commas between json objects

Tags: python, json, format

```
//text comment// 

{"data": 

3}

{"data": 

4}

////////////
///extra
```

I have a .json of multiple JSON objects like above that I'd like to parse in Python. However I need to remove all slashes, and text in between or simply after the double slashes. I also need to make the JSON objects into a list by adding brackets and commas to obtain something like this, to properly parse it.

```
[{"data": 

3}, 

{"data": 4}]
```

What's the best way to do this? My primary concern is about the comments, as I've seen similar questions about adding the brackets and commas.

Comment: please add your attempt in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file's not too complex like above, maybe this could work

```
import regex as re
import json

f = open("brokenjson.txt", "r")
a = f.read()

a = re.sub(re.compile("//.*?\n" ) ,"" ,a) # remove all occurrence single-line comments (//COMMENT\n ) from string
a = a.replace("\n", "")                   # remove all breakline from string
a = a.replace("}{", "},{")                # {x:y} {h:j} => {x:y},{h:j}
a = "[" + a + "]"
b = json.loads(a)
print(b)
```

[image]

It wouldn't work if your file have multiple key-value pair missing comma in each json

`{ x:n      t:r}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I'm getting [{"data": 3},{"data": 4}///extra] when printing a after all the replacements.

Comment: @hedebyhedge huh that's weird, can you upload your file so I can check?

Comment: [**Please do not upload images of text (code/input/output/errors, or otherwise) on Stack Overflow**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).